# Have Google Desktop to index a website without visiting every page manually?

Tags: google-desktop-search

Has any enterprising soul figured out how to get Google Desktop to index a website without having to actually visit every page on that site with your browser? or perhaps created an extension which causes one's browser to follow all links unattended?

For reasons beyond my understanding or control our internal website does not have a search engine and I'm tired of hunting through it piecemeal for pdf forms etc. I'm sure eventually we'll have one but in the meantime I need to find stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken the poor cousin route of mirroring the site to my local drive with http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm:

```
wget --mirror http://internal.domain.org/
```